# Error: Package dependencies must specify a version range. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to install a package in ASP.net Core, I'm using the full .net framework, but I'm getting an error, the package I'm trying to install is Dropnet, it's not the first time this message is showed, this has happened other times too, the message I'm getting is:

```
error:   Package dependencies must specify a version range.
```

This is my project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "AWSSDK": "2.3.55.2",
    "AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2": "3.3.0.2",
    "Dropbox.Api": "3.6.0",
    "DropNet": "1.10.23",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "",
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "MongoDB.Bson": "2.3.0",
    "MongoDB.Driver": "2.3.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "SharedClasses": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }

    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"

    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Did you happen to figure it out? I'd like to know what went wrong for you.